# AWS ECS: multiple containers deployed but only one container on port 80 is discoverable

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run my docker containers on aws ecs using aws-cli (instance-type is EC2)

I have a docker-compose file with 2 services.

```
version:'3'
services:
 service-one:
  image: dockerhub/image1
  ports:
   - "4500:9090"
 service-two:
  image: dockerhub/image2
  ports:
  - "80:3030"
```

When i run this on aws ecs using ecs-cli:

```
ecs-cli compose service up --config-name config --ecs-profile etc
```

My containers fire up successfully But **ONLY one** container (the service-two) shows up on port 80, i cannot see my service-one on port 4500 even though it is running successfully inside docker (docker container ps). I also tried running service-one on port 80 and then it showed up.

**Summarizing:** i can't discover any container from the web unless it in running on port 80.

Comment: Check your security group, seems like just port 80 is public

Comment: You may want to have an ALB in front of your cluster

Comment: @Adiii You're correct!!! I'm a noob with AWS should have figured it out. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the security group associated with your EC2 instance and on `inbound rules` add a new rule of type `http`, as Port range your container port (`4500`), as source, **just for testing** (you are exposing your service to the world), select source `Anywhere`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @Madeo's answer, you need to open port 4500 in your security group of the ec2 instance. You could add custom tcp rule on port 4500 and open it to 0.0.0.0, ::/0 . But this should only be for testing purposes. When you are sure it is working, update the security group to accept traffic only from where you want it to (e.g. a load balancer).